# How to reset password of Keystore file

Tags: android, flutter, keystore, android-keystore

I am facing issue in Android Keystore is giving an error for wrong password, we need to reset it.

I have followed this but no revert from Google yet;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJRwPJLz71M

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: I think you should just wait for google to review your email request. It may take very long time due to Christmas holidays

Comment: @SergeyGovyazin I have sent mail in first week of December. Yet I haven't received any update/response on mail.